# Angular cli - how to add proxy for links in JSON response

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-cli

We were facing the CORS issue, so we had added the proxy by configuring the  proxy.conf.json file with below config

```
  {
  "/restapi/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
   }
 }
```

CORS issue was resolved with above proxy, now all response include the links for my next request as below, the response links are still pointing back directly to Server(running on port 8080).That is pretty much expected as we did not do anything to patch the links from response’s payload, any suggestion on how to resolve this?

```
    "_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8080/restapi/services"
},
"http://identifiers.emc.com/product-info": {
"href": "http://localhost:8080/restapi/product-info"
},
"http://identifiers.emc.com/tenants": {
"href": "http://localhost:8080/restapi/systemdata/tenants"
},
"http://identifiers.emc.com/tenant": {
"href": "http://localhost:8080/restapi/systemdata/tenants/97bf9fd5-710c-47e8-984e-050ebbf212e3"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This might help https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md